# Display part of the input using shell script

Tags: shell

How can I get the output below using shell commands?

Input as below:

```
Nexus-test-1.12.3
Producer-1.13.3
Testing-one-word-1.12
```

Output should be

```
Nexus-test
Producer
Testing-one-word
```

Comment: Remove everything after and including the first `.`

Comment: `sed` would be a good choice.

Comment: Sorry there is a change in question

Answer (score 1):

I really struggle with whether or not to answer this, because it's incredibly trivial and it appears that zero effort has been made to figure it out.  But....just do:

```
cut -d . -f 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it, hope you can do a search first.

### awk:

```
awk -F'.' '{$0=$1}7'
```

### sed:

```
sed 's/[.]*//'
```

### grep:

```
grep -Po '^[^.]*'
```

Comment: Sorry, There is a change in question